# Error compiling Linux kernel module using custom system calls

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, kernel-module

I'll walk you through step by step

First I edit 3 files in my Linux kernel directory

1. Open `LINUX_DIRECTORY/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl` and add the custom calls i'm implementing – using the appropriate format
2. Declare them here: `LINUX_DIRECTORY/include/linux/syscalls.h` – using the appropriate format:
3. Open `LINUX_DIRECTORY/Makefile` and add the directory I'm storing my new system calls to the `core-y` line:

   core-y    := usr/ my_system_call_directory/

Here's where I'm having issues. Inside `LINUX_DIRECTORY/my_system_call_directory` I add a C file with my custom system call definitions and its corresponding `Makefile`. I leave the definitions empty because inside the C file for my kernel module I declare an extern function (my custom system call) and define a separate function which is set to my extern function:

```
extern long (*start_shuttle)(void); 

long my_start_shuttle(void) {

  // stuff here 

}


int init_module(void) {

  // stuff here

  start_shuttle = my_start_shuttle;

  // more stuff
}
```

After recompiling the kernel I try to `make` the kernel module and get a `no definition for start_shuttle` error.

Is this because I left the definition for `start_shuttle` blank in `my_system_call_directory`? Should it match exactly the `my_start_shuttle` I defined in the kernel module or is there something special I'm supposed to add? I'm asking dumb questions in advance because it takes so long for my machine to recompile Linux and I'm not sure what to change. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. For anyone as slow as me, you have to use a wrapper and a stub.

So for this example, in the `my_system_call_directory`, in the `c` file for your new system call definitions, you need something like this:

```
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/export.h>

// initialize the stub function to be NULL

long (*start_shuttle)(void) = NULL;

EXPORT_SYMBOL(start_shuttle);

// wrapper

asmlinkage long sys_start_shuttle(void)
{
if (start_shuttle)
    return start_shuttle();
else 
    return -ENOSYS;
}
```